# Restricting Envelope Access

Tags: docusignapi

The Permission Set option "Allow view and manage envelope rights through API" automatically gives the API user access to view all envelopes in the account regardless of who owns/sent the envelope. Is it possible to restrict the user to only access their own envelopes/folders?

We have multiple teams sharing a DocuSign account. One team wants to build an API integration but we can't allow them to access or view envelopes sent by other teams in the same account. Do we need to move this team with an API integration to a separate account?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `new Permission Set` or `do not` assign any permission set to API user which has `Allow view and manage envelope rights through API` setting enabled. If a permission set assigned to an API user does not have `Allow view and manage envelope rights through API` setting enabled then that API user will not be able to see any other's envelopes.